# Presto SQL category counter

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following table

```
cust_id | category | counts
1       | food     |   2
1       | pets     |   5
3       | pets     |   3
```

I would like to get this output

```
cust_id | food_count | pets_count
1       |    2       |  5
3       |    0       |  3
```

Where the number of columns map all unique values in the `category` column. Do you know how that can be done in Presto SQL? If I were doing this in pySpark I would use CountVectorizer but I'm a bit struggling with SQL.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY and sum on condition. For example using [`if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#id1) function:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (cust_id, category, counts) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'food', 2),
        (1, 'pets', 5),
        (3, 'pets', 3)
) 

--query
select cust_id, sum(if(category = 'food', counts, 0)) food_counts, sum(if(category = 'pets', counts, 0)) pets_counts
from dataset
group by cust_id
```

Output:

| cust_id | food_counts | pets_counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 0 | 3 |